# insert/select with a condition

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way to select A unless its null then select B instead?

I am writing a trigger, my code is

```
insert into tbl_a(userid, obj)
select p.author, new.id 
FROM user_comment AS p 
WHERE p.id=new.parent
```

however `new.parent` is a nullable long (i'll switch to foreign key once supported in system.data.sqlite)
if its null i get 0 results and no insert. I would like to use `join media as m on m.id=new.media_id` and return `m.user_id` if `new.parent` is null. So how do i write the select to return `m.author` if parent isnt null (which i'll return `p.author` like the above)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IFNULL(col1, col2)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull). If `col1` is not null, it is returned. If `col1` is null, `col2` is returned.

Comment: excellent. can i write a select statement in the params? do i have to do  ifnull(a, b) select name1 as a ..... basically i want to know if ifnull is before the select or if the select is inside it (or if i need to google an example)

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing. Could you describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish, and what are the desired actions taken in each case?